# Setting Custom Privacy for FB graph API posts to feed stopped working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

It worked perfectly fine for a few month, but suddenly stopped recognizing CUSTOM privacy settings. If custom settings allows a list of friends, get a "friends value was not recognized" error, if it denies list of friends, privacy is simply set to "SELF".

```
   $custom =  ',"friends": "SOME_FRIENDS","allow": "' + $ids + '"';
   var params = {};
   params['message'] = $message;
   params['name'] = $name;
   params['link'] = $url;
   params['caption'] = $caption;
   params['privacy'] = '{"value":"'+$privacy + '"' + $custom + '}'; 

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert(response.error.message);
  } else {
    if (response && response.id) {
    alert("success");
  }
});
```

Anyone ran into this issue? Any help is appreciated!